# Adminer 4.3.1 - Only shows one database

Tags: mysql, adminer

I have recently moved hosts and I can not get adminer 4.3.1, downloaded today to see more than one database.  Why it has chosen that one I do not know.  The host company copied all my data from the original host. The databases are MySQL.

I am running Adminer from a directory which uses directory protection via an authorised user and that works OK.

AM only shows one of 6 databases. There does not seem to be a problem with any functions, with the chosen database.  All the databases have different passwords.

phpMyAdmin via cPanel sees all the databases OK.

I did click SERVER as suggested by someone, but that still only shows the one database.

Any ideas as to what I can try to either fix or at least get more information to help to solve the problem.

Comment: login with a different user/password.

Comment: Thanks - Is the user the name of the database ?

Comment: I just assumed you have multible users as you wrote "All the databases have different passwords". Idk their names.

Comment: I have never consciously created a user.  I just created a password as part of the new database app in cPanel and I connect to the database in php with the database name as the user and the password I chose.  I had not appreciated the login logout of adminer as I never seemed to need it and on my previous hosts with the same databases and different passwords - they were all displayed. - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have discovered the solution to my problems.

My original host used standard MYSQL, but the host I moved to Krystal Hosting use MariaDB for their MySQL.

I think my problem was caused by the databases I transferred not having strong enough passwords.  The database that was displayed had a very good password.

Having eventually tracked down the original passwords I wrote a php script to connect to all the databases.  They all failed except for one, which was the one showing up in Adminer 431.

To get around this I created a user with a STRONG password (the usual spec chars, upper and lower case) and gave that user access to all the databases and behold they all connected.

The strange aspect to this is that I could see all the databases and access them in phpMyAdmin via cPanel and I was in the process of dumping the SQL from the database and creating new databases and then uploading the dumped SQL, I found I needed to add a USER, which had not been the case previously (std MYSQL), as that only needed a password on database creation.

Aren't computers fun - the biggest jigsaw puzzle in the world, but the sizes and colours of some of the pieces change more often than you can keep up with and so the puzzle is never completed.